# How can I give a dynamic class to vue3 main div #app?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to give a dynamic class to my vue3 app's main div.

When I create the app with the commands down below, it creates a main div tag which has an id `app`. I can change the styling with css but since I don't have it in the page I can not change class dynamically.

**Code to create the app**

```js
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

#### What I want to do

```js
<div id="app" :class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: In Vue3 when you create the app it creates the main <div> tag with `app` id. But you can not reach it in the code because it is being created in the building process. @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Oh, I see. Good to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do that with Vue directly.

Defining `:class="myClass"` on root element will not be reactive.

...but you can handle that manually.

you can use `this.$el.parentElement` in a method (like `mounted`) and that will allow you to manage the class attribute. (there are several methods like `addClass`, `toggleClass` on the [classList  API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList))

If you want that to be reactive, you can use a `computed` or `watch` to modify that based on some other parameter, but you'd need to provide more context to have more detail on that.

If possible though (depends on the setup/need), you could nest the application in another level of `div`, so you can control the class.

Answer (score 5):

You could add property that represent your class then use watch to update the your root element using `document.querySelector('#app').classList = [val]`, i made the following example that illustrate a real work example which is the mode change from dark to light and vice-versa, i added property called `mode` and i change it using a button click event then i watch it to update the root element class :

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue;
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
      mode: 'is-light'
    }
  },
  watch: {
    mode(val) {
      document.querySelector('#app').classList = [val]
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 4px
}

.is-dark {
  background: #454545;
  color: white
}

.is-light {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  color: #222
}

button {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: transparent;
  background: #4545ee
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-rc.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="is-dark">

  <button @click="mode= 'is-dark'" class="is-dark">
Dark
</button>

  <button @click="mode= 'is-light'" class="is-light">
Light
</button>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti quidem aspernatur provident fugit impedit esse itaque iusto iure voluptatem eaque?
  </p>

</div>
```